# Running app with pm2 and --watch fails to serve css, works without --watch or pm2

Tags: css, node.js, express, stylus, pm2

I'm trying to learn how to use node.js, and I've started with [this tutorial](http://www.clock.co.uk/blog/a-simple-website-in-nodejs-with-express-jade-and-stylus). When I start node directly with `node app.js`, everything works fine. When I run node as a service under PM2 with `pm2 start app.js`, everything also works fine.

However, if I try to get PM2 to automatically restart my node app when I change my file(s) using `pm2 start app.js --watch`, it stops correctly serving my CSS, and I get **ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE** in Chrome when trying to view the CSS file's route.

The PM2 error log is empty. The output log only records a GET request for the website root, with a 304 response code. If I use node directly, the console logs a 200 response for the root, a 200 response for the style.css the first page load, and a 304 response for the CSS on each subsequent page load for the same nod session.

I've tried specifying exactly what files to watch with PM2 using `processes.json` as detailed in [Express 4 + pm2 watch not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27882759/express-4-pm2-watch-not-working), but it doesn't seem to affect the results.

```js
// ./app.js
var express = require('express'),
    stylus = require('stylus),
    nib = require('nib'),
    app = express();

function compile(str, path) {
    return stylus(str).set('filename', path).use(nib());
}

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(stylus.middleware({ src: __dirname + '/public', compile: compile }));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'My Title' });
});
app.listen(3000);
```

```
//- ./views/layout.jade
doctype
html
  head
    title #{title}
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  body
    header
      h1 #{title}
    .container
      .main-content
        block content
      .sidebar
        block sidebar
    footer
      p Running on node with Express, Jade, and Stylus
```

```css
/* ./public/stylesheets/style.styl */
@import 'nib'
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand')
global-reset()

main-color = #fa5b4d
background-color = #faf9f0

body
  font-family 'Georgia'
  background-color background-color
  color #444

header
  font-family 'Quicksand'
  padding 50px 10px
  color #fff
  font-size 25px
  text-align center

  background-color main-color
  border-bottom 1px solid darken(main-color, 30%)
  text-shadow 0px -1px 0px darken(main-color, 30%)

.container
  width 500px
  margin 50px auto
  overflow hidden

.main-content
  float left
  width 300px

    p
      margin-bottom 20px

.sidebar
  float left
  width 200px

  .widget
    border-radius 3px
    border 1px solid #ccc
    margin-left 20px
    background-color background-color
    box-shadow inset 0px 0px 0px 3px rgba(#fff, 0.8), 0px 3px 0px -2px rgba(#000, 0.1)

    h1
      font-family 'Quicksand'
      margin 13px 10px 4px
      padding-bottom 10px
      border-bottom 1px dotted #ddd
      border-radius 2px 2px 0px 0px
      margin-bottom 10px

    p
      font-size 13px
      padding 0px 10px
      margin-bottom 10px

p
  line-height 1.0

footer
  width 500px
  margin 50px auto
  border-top 1px dotted #ccc
  padding-top 5px
  font-size 13px
```

```html
<!-- generated html (whitespace added for readability) -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header><h1>My Title</h1></header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="main-content">
                <p>Vivamus hendrerit arcu sed erat molestie
                   vehicula. Sed auctor neque eu tellus
                   rhoncus ut eleifend nibh porttitor. Ut in.</p>
                <p>Donnec congue lacinia dui, a porttitor
                   lectus condimentum laoreet. Nunc eu
                   ullamcorper orci. Quisque eget odio ac
                   lectus vestibulum faucibus eget in metus.
                   In pellentesque faucibus vestibulum. Nulla
                   at nulla justo, eget luctus tortor.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar">
                <div class="widget">
                    <h1>Widget</h1>
                    <p>Sed auctor neque eu tellus rhoncus ut
                       eleifend nibh porttitor. Ut in nulla enim.</p>
                    <p>Vivamus hendrerit arcu sed erat molestie
                       vehicula.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <p>Running on node with Express, Jade and Stylus</p>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code above is operated without any problems in `pm2 --watch` (node 5.7.1, pm2 - 1.0.2).

Comment: @stdob--, when I use `node app.js` or `pm2 start app.js`, I get: http://i.imgur.com/YRMMGM5.jpg but when I use `pm2 start app.js --watch` I get http://i.imgur.com/ZKEalCs.jpg because the site won't serve the CSS file correctly.

Comment: I'm having an issue with pm2 too in my production environment. When a user fills out a form and clicks submit, the form Posts to the server via `router.post('/landing-page', function(req, res){ ... res.redirect('/thankyou') }`. Unfortunately, when pm2 is running, `/thankyou` loads and the chrome dev tools shows that all the linked css and js files are failing with a 502 (a few randomly come through as 200). I figured out that when I run the application via the $`node app.js` command this problem goes away.