# Expressjs pm2 ignore watch public/images folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pm2

I have a website using nodejs. Problem is when user upload images the site stop working. That because of PM2 restart server when file change I think. How to solve this problem.
thank you

Comment: pm2 does not automatically restart the processes it manages unless you specifically ask it to. Alternatively you could save the files in a folder outside of your working directory, which is actually better as the data should be separated from the code. Also please show us the log files by issuing `pm2 logs <process-name>`

Answer (score 45, accepted):

PM2 has special flag `--ignore-watch` flag.

Try creating file `process.json` in the same directory where your app.js/index.js is and paste this:

```
{
  "watch": ["server", "client"],
  "ignore_watch" : ["node_modules", "public/images"],
  "watch_options": {
    "followSymlinks": false
  }
}
```

More on that topic: http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/watch-and-restart/

Comment: where to put process.json? this is my directory http://prntscr.com/bm1bms

Comment: Next to your main server file/in project root folder.

Comment: What is the exact line: pm2 -ignore-watch ? please make it more detail

Comment: Got it follow this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27882759/express-4-pm2-watch-not-working

Comment: the `ignore_watch` option works also with pm2 ecosystem files: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/watch-and-restart/

Answer (score 19):

A simple explanation, from actual experience

create a json file in the root folder of the the expressjs application. It can have any name, but I used pm2-process.json for clarity

```
{
    "script": "bin/www",
    "watch": true,
    "ignore_watch": ["log"],
    "watch_options": {
        "followSymlinks": false
    },
    "name": "YOUR_PM2_PROCESS_NAME"
}
```

To start your pm2 service from terminal, in the root folder of the express application:

```
pm2 start pm2-process.json
```

That's it. Really simple. There are many other options but this is the bare functional minimum .

Fields explanation:

- *script* - the script to run the express application
- *watch* - a boolean flag to control if pm2 watches (or not) the folder
- *ignore_watch* - if watch is on, then tell pm2 which folders to ignore watching (in other words, this is a watch monitor exclusion list)
- *name* - the name of the pm2 process ('service'). Set it to your application name of choice.

The full documentation is here: http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/#attributes-available

Note: I left the node_modules folder out of the ignore_watch array in the example above, because I want pm2 to restart the service after a git pull and npm i that causes a change in the node modules. However it easy to ignore node_modules or any other folder (e.g., temp, public, etc.) by editing the array values

Answer (score 0):

Please use --spa

for example

pm2 serve build 3001 --name "any-name" --spa

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).