# PM2: ignore watch folder glob pattern

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2

I want pm2 to stop watching folders which have a name like `cache` or `tmp`.

I tried a lot of manners in my `app.json` config file :

```
{"apps": [{
    "name": "BSTAT",
    "script": "./server/app.js",
    "watch": true,
    "ignore_watch": [
        "HERE IS WHAT I HAVE TRIED ==>",
        "*cache*",
        "*/cache",
        "cache/",
        "*cache/*"
    ],
}]}
```

and also saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38070869/expressjs-pm2-ignore-watch-public-images-folder) who doesn't seem to have an exemple of that case.

The only way that I find to resolve the problem was to put the exact path like `server/my-module/cache`

I can not bring myself to think this is not possible...that's why I request your help :)

Comment: you can just do `ignore_watch : [cache,...multiple item goes here...] ` , this will completely iignore cache dir,

Comment: Hi, tried but doesn't seem to work....thx however

Comment: it can be in any directory ?

Comment: Yes, like `server/module/tmp` or `tests/tmp`...etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need a regex for this, e.g.:

```
ignore_watch : ['./**/*tests.js', ]
```

this pattern will ignore all files with name "tests.js" in all project folders

Comment: How could I ignore the same folder ? I am trying this regex but doesnt work: ["./"]