# nodemon-check for specific files for changes

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon

I'm using nodemon in my nodejs application to track changes in any of the project files. If there is any change discovered, the project has to restart. Nodemon does this job perfectly.

But **my requirement is to check for a specific file for any change** (Right now, Nodemon checks the entire project files for changes)

I have tried using this: ***Nodemon -e “.js” app.js*** which will only check files with extension .js. How can I check one specific file with nodemon.

And can anyone suggest a module(for the same purpose) in nodejs which can be used in production level( since nodemon is used only for development purposes?)

Comment: nodemon -d ./dir/file.js app.js

Comment: Use pm2 for the production, it's a process management tool

Comment: @Ankit: Thanks for the reply! But that doesnt work. Its still restarting if any of the file is changed.

Comment: @Ankit: Is there something like a config file in Nodemon where I can specify which all files need to be monitored?

Comment: i think it is not possible with nodemon, but if you want to do this using pm2, follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27882759/express-4-pm2-watch-not-working#answer-27893721)

Comment: nodemon server.js -w server.js

Answer (score 0):

[supervisor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supervisor) package lets you watch specified files. For example:

```
supervisor -w folder1,folder2,folder3,somescript.js,otherscript.js app.js
```

> Remember to install it with -g flag